# Add subview as another layout programatically?

Tags: android, layout

I have two layout files that I would like to use as part of another layout, how would I do that?

For i.e, I have a single layout at /res/layout/single.xml. I want to use that layout as a `gridView` cell layout and another layout  named "sub_view.xml" which I want to add in single layout, I know how to do it using include tag but didn't manage to add in `gridview'cell`,
or 
simply I want to add the sub_view xml as view in single.xml layout file programmatically.

Comment: May be `inflater.inflate(R.layout.single, null)` will be useful for you.

Comment: If you want to add single.xml as gridview cell then you have to add that in your gridview adapter public View getView() { }

Answer (score 0):

You could first inflate the single.xml and then the sub_view.xml:

```
    GridView simpleView = (GridView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.simple, null);
   getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sub_view, simpleView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have inflated the single.xml, and the root element of single.xml is a `ViewGroup`

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
ViewGroup single = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single,null);
View sub_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_view,null);
single.addView(sub_view);
```